# Conjugate gradient: $O(n^2)$ or $O(n^3)$?

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to understand the time complexity for the conjugate gradient method, when a fair amount of system details are considered.

The first thing I'm not quite sure about, is the dependence. Previous answers ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607423/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-conjugate-gradient-method)) assert it is $O(m\sqrt{k})$, where $m$ is the number of non-zero entries. Then given $d$ the density of the matrix (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)), this would result in a $O(dn^2\sqrt{k})$ complexity.

On the other hand, different sources ([here](https://stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/conj_grad_slides.pdf) and [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=V8gWP031-hEC&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=conjugate+gradient+time+complexity+n%5E3&source=bl&ots=8Ff_cFO0a-&sig=ACfU3U3mhwD2lAYWojBK_CsPknI2aZ7nAw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi369O3qvjoAhUmwqYKHZw8B9cQ6AEwCHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=conjugate%20gradient%20time%20complexity%20n%5E3&f=false)) report that the $O(n^2)$ time complexity is actually that of the iteration, and since $n$ iterations are needed at most, the effective time complexity is actually $O(n^3)$ or better, $O(dn^3\sqrt{k})$, where we intend "*time complexity*" as "*the time required to obtain the solution of the linear system, as a function of the matrix size*".

On the other hand, I have found many additional confusing (for me) details. Particularly, they stated:

- that $n$ is the number of maximum steps to find the solution *in theory*, yet not in practice, due to round-off errors (which would imply some even larger dependence on $n$);
- that $n$ is the number of maximum steps to find the *exact* solution, but that a lot less steps are needed to achieve an approximate solution (which would explain why the additional $n$ term is occasionally discarded in the time complexity?).

So I wanted to settle this once and for all: what is the time complexity of the conjugate gradient method for solving a linear system, for a generic non-sparse matrix?

Comment: For a dense matrix with **exact** arithmetic CG takes at most $n$ iterations with a matrix multiply at each iteration so the (time) cost is $n^3$. If the condition number features in the complexity then this is inexact arithmetic.